# Using Javascript and PHP to generate images using a TTF

Tags: php, javascript, gd

I am having trouble using a script I found at http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/use_a_custom_font_on_your_website.html

The problem is, when I load a page, the text shows up then each word is replaced by a generated image of it using the PHP GD lib.

It creates a flicker effect that I can't seem to get rid of. There are options is the js file:

var hideFlicker = true;
var hideFlickerCSS = "replacement-screen.css";
var hideFlickerTimeout = 0;

But when I change any of those settings, nothing happens.
Please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For what you seem to be trying to do, image replacement is an extremely outdated method. All the ninja-devs are using technology called @font-face for their fonts and font replacements.

It's simpler, doesn't require anything to happen on the server and text on the page can be modified dynamically.

You can use services like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ or http://code.google.com/webfonts for ready made font packages.

If you have a custom font (that you have a license for) you can create an @font-face package for it, using fontsquirrel's @font-face generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

And then you just define your fonts in the CSS. Simple, elegant and works in 99% of browsers (yes, even IE6)

Cheers!